# What is the difference between Red Hat and Fedora?

Tags: fedora, redhat-enterprise-linux, comparison

I am confused between the 2 Linux Distros

1. Red Hat
2. Fedora

I had a believed that RedHat has been reduxed to make Fedora. However seems that is not the case.

Further, when I tried to download RedHat, it again took me to the Fedora website.

Can someone please explain what is the difference between these two distros?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are wanting to try Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) check out [CentOS](http://centos.org). It's exactly the same as RHEL but with copyrighted RedHat logos removed.

Basically it boils down to:

- **RHEL = CentOS = Oracle Unbreakable Linux** - Server OS, with stable packages and 'certified' to run certain proprietary enterprise software. Has ancient version of most packages (by Linux standards)
- **Fedora** - Has all the spiffy new stuff. Good as desktop or development server. Has all the cool new toys. If you buy Oracle softare/support contract and then call them about using their database on Fedora they will laugh an evil laugh and tell you its *NOT* Supported!

Comment: That is the exact piece of information I wanted !.

Answer (score 9):

Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) is an enterprise-class Linux distro whose goal is long-term API/ABI stability. Fedora Linux (Fedora) is a developer-class Linux distro whose goal is to test and showcase new technologies. Every few years a new version of RHEL comes out, containing stabilized forms of the technologies previously used in Fedora.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this http://www.redhat.com/rhel/migrate/whichlinux/ it might help.

Comment: Nice, simply put Red Hat means money ! ... Fedora is Free !

Comment: @Arkapravo: The money really isn't the important part. There are several no-money clones of RHEL available.